# How to hide button in Desktop Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop, jetbrains-compose

I am developing an app with [Desktop Compose Multi-Platform](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-mpp/).
I need to hide the button when it has been clicked.
Please see below code:

```
OutlinedButton(
        onClick = {
            // Perform an operation
            // Hide the button
        }) {
        Text(text = "CLick Here")
    }
```

As compared to android, Desktop Compose does not have visibility modifiers.
for e.g. `visibility = View.GONE`

So how to hide the button on the `onClick` event ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any view modifications in Compose are done using state variables.

If you need the view to be completely removed, you can do it like this:

```
var isButtonVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
if (isButtonVisible) {
    OutlinedButton(
        onClick = {
            // Perform an operation
            isButtonVisible = false
        }) {
        Text(text = "CLick Here")
    }
}
```

If you want to save space in the layout, you can simply hide it with `Modifier.alpha`. For example, if you have a row with a couple of elements and you don't want them to move after the button disappears.

```
var isButtonVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
OutlinedButton(
    onClick = {
        // Perform an operation
        isButtonVisible = false
    },
    modifier = Modifier.alpha(if (isButtonVisible) 1f else 0f)
) {
    Text(text = "CLick Here")
}
```

I suggest you check out with state in Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles.